# Issue with docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker image ,
There is some issue with it
How can reinstall it ?

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you are trying to do.  Can you edit your post to include what commands you're running and what your Dockerfile looks like?

Comment: done , can you please take a look at the question again ?

Answer (score 1):

you can list your installed images with `docker images`.  To remove an image, you can `docker image rm <ID>`.  For example:

```
➜  ~ docker images
REPOSITORY                              TAG                                              IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples   latest                                           601ba7083976        2 days ago          190MB
ubuntu                                  latest                                           74435f89ab78        3 days ago          73.9MB
<none>                                  <none>                                           0065b5c5e1d8        5 days ago          607MB
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples   <none>                                           d9ed8f8f6eac        3 weeks ago         190MB
docker/desktop-storage-provisioner      v1.1                                             e704287ce753        2 months ago        41.8MB
➜  ~ docker image rm 006
Deleted: sha256:0065b5c5e1d8b210c7447349be227d31bc3f90d25a77d8f25ae8d0d7cef5f381
Deleted: sha256:2ac7e1261af05d93e84282f56f5724d42eb78964076a128218fe2a9229f78ab4
Deleted: sha256:ad1b0388aa08b02e9e5b3b169a0d2d68472a9ce2125f32997b801afcfa9b4b72
Deleted: sha256:42d9a26918bca67ad9a48844a2e9b0ee5b0140437434246d571d35805aca2cf8
Deleted: sha256:c22539cbd6641b59aabc092ca1f36b8676f66f95c2cd844db07f182b0f1579a4
Deleted: sha256:589c738b865a4f4af3c6f26a15c7e2cddd190f64d73a44d37a4285f2716d0001
Deleted: sha256:950fab5a4cedc4cca74c072213d92954f743adb33c4f278eba0e6ec5428f5a55
Deleted: sha256:f7cc1c88cf60aba12c88e14e404fd603d739ce2fea9eb5e214501d7e1a39d60b
Deleted: sha256:2b5aee3d59b9a88cb77af2eea04bcb92d2da3c9a3852b881cb9aba6f57761abb
Deleted: sha256:0c3f9b359db9120101b69a56b869fcdaa33c0afd69ac7ec508113ee0758ae46f
Deleted: sha256:610c86760b9736093a1d139b1ce583f3e2a223bcb4ac0b6b651c929ed6d12764
Deleted: sha256:617910c3b61adafca208167b78f44131f01641e71f4b89ff250658c370412a00
Deleted: sha256:f2264424f15b78168ec7441812c731d22fc0891c274ec82c126a01325f1527e4
Deleted: sha256:1491e7cc69501585954300620cc88545a174d94583c066ad4dbe844237b70a6e
Deleted: sha256:3734e1b61819b6e243cd93702be7669aba9a42ef21e5d65fb92aa18aaae04326
Deleted: sha256:d518876dd3923dac7010a2409b18331aa32f87324598d1c0e6688d688d66fbc3
Deleted: sha256:20e9bb03e9e5ebadf48871d9d8e3e76043a1c959a2a0a334a78943cc8f12b970
Deleted: sha256:d7d0291bc1ea6f5625218c840885b847fec43deedd9103eb075638dd44c2fcc8
Deleted: sha256:a48bbb1b4b965ce41b9e89d246619eb647f42a1726232b36b582c6e5cd70a1ae
```

To reinstall, just do `docker run <imagename>` or `docker pull <imagename>`.

Comment: Image name or image id ?

Comment: I'm not following where you're asking about.

Comment: REPOSITORY                                                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
m2_frontend                                             latest              97arwrwrr9ff13c9ad        4 weeks ago

Comment: docker pull <imagename>   where image name = IMAGE ID or repository ?

Comment: `docker run` will automatically pull the components if you give it the image name, and then start a new container from that image.  `docker pull` simply gets the image onto your machine.

Comment: Thankyou  very much for your response frank , but i have some issue with image and i want to  reinstall that image doc i need to - docker run (repo name) for that

Comment: Yes, that is the image name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216319/discussion-between-devmage-and-frank).